# Set elements that are not found to Null/Empty instead of skipping them

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to figure out how to set elements that are not found to null instead of skipping the loop. There are cases when the Name or Title or Company is missing so I will like to have that empty in my csv. My knowledge is limited when it comes to python so I could really use some help.

The problem with what I already have is that if the exception is thrown, the line is skipped altogether. What would be the best way to achieve what I am looking for? Would a pandas dataframe help with this? If so, how should I write it? Should I write to csv in a different way?

```
filename = "C:\\scrape.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "Name, Company, Title\n"

f.write(headers)

names = []
for value in names:
#Search
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl09_FindFirstName']").send_keys(value)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl11_FindContacts']").click()
try:
    for i in range(5):
        try:
            Name = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl11_DisplayName_"+str(i)+"']").text
            Company = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl11_CompanyNamePanel_"+str(i)+"']").text
            Title = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl11_CompanyTitlePanel_"+str(i)+"']").text

            f.write(Name.replace(",", "|") + "," + Company.replace(",", "|") + "," + Title.replace(",", "|") + "\n")

            #print("Name: " + browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl11_DisplayName_"+str(i)+"']").text)
            #print("Company: " + browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl11_CompanyNamePanel_"+str(i)+"']").text)
            #print("Title: " + browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl11_CompanyTitlePanel_"+str(i)+"']").text)
        except NoSuchElementException:        
            continue                                                                                  
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
f.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `find_element_by`, you can use `find_elements_by`. This way it will create a list of elements found, or an ***empty*** list if it doesn't find a matching element instead of throwing *`NoSuchElementException`*.

Try this:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl09_FindFirstName']").send_keys(value)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl11_FindContacts']").click()
for i in range(5):
    Name = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl11_DisplayName_"+str(i)+"']").text
    Company = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl11_CompanyNamePanel_"+str(i)+"']").text
    Title = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl11_CompanyTitlePanel_"+str(i)+"']").text

    if not Name: name = "None"
    else: name = Name[0].text

    if not Company: company = "None"
    else: company = Company[0].text

    if not Title: title = "None"
    else: title = Title[0].text

    f.write(name.replace(",", "|") + "," + company.replace(",", "|") + "," + title.replace(",", "|") + "\n")                                                                             
f.close()
```

Comment: @PixelEistein This works great and has indeed solved my problem. I ended up using this approach. Cheers!

Comment: The detailed analysis was very useful

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
filename = "C:\\scrape.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "Name, Company, Title\n"

f.write(headers)

names = []
for value in names:
    #Search
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl09_FindFirstName']").send_keys(value)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl11_FindContacts']").click()


    for i in range(5):
        Names = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl11_DisplayName_" + str(i) + "']")
        if len(Names) == 0:
            name = 'Empty'
        else:
            name = Names[0].text

        Companys = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl11_CompanyNamePanel_" + str(i) + "']")
        if len(Companys) == 0:
            company = 'Empty'
        else:
            company = Companys[0].text

        Titles = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl11_CompanyTitlePanel_" + str(i) + "']")
        if len(Titles) == 0:
            title = 'Empty'
        else:
            title = Titles[0].text

        f.write(name.replace(",", "|") + "," + company.replace(",", "|") + "," + title.replace(",", "|") + "\n")

f.close()
```

As you can see you don't need `try/catch` anymore. If there is no elements found the element will be set to 'Empty' string. `browser.find_elements...` does not throw `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: I found this answer really useful in understanding what I was dealing with. I ended up using the "shorter" version provided by the other answer. Is there a reason why I should use `len` instead of `if not` other than preference?

Comment: No, the shorter version is good as well. If it was useful you can upvote my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have solved the issue of skipping lines, but do not include any information about Pandas as the question asks about.

With regard to Pandas, you could potentially use a dataframe instead of writing each line to a file as you did. Then, you can use the dataframe export method of [to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to get your data. I personally use [this link](http://pbpython.com/pandas-list-dict.html) to reference many different ways to get your data into a dataframe.

The way that I would do it is to append each of your variables in the current `try` block to separate lists comprised of all instances of those variables. In this example, start with three blank lists

```
names_list = []
companies_list = []
titles_list = []
```

then in your loop to strip the values

```
names_list.append(name)
companes_list.append(company)
titles_list.append(title)
```

Then I'd `tuple()` those lists and add them to one large list called `data` and create a list called `labels` to hold the column names.

```
names_tup = tuple(names_list)
companies_tup = tuple(companies_list)
titles_tup = tuple(titles_list)
data = [names_tup, companies_tup, titles_tup]
labels = ['name', 'company', 'title']
```

Then convert your data to a dataframe as in the link referenced above.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=labels)
```

Finally, save your dataframe as a csv:

```
fileLocation = 'path\\to\\filename.csv'
df.to_csv(path_or_buf = fileLocation, sep=',')
```

Comment: This addressed my question and it's a valuable lesson. Your answer it is greatly appreciated @BenG-TW. The only problem that I ran into was AssertionError X columns passed, passed data had N columns. If anyone has the same problem, I managed to solve it by using itertools: `pd.DataFrame.from_records((_ for _ in itertools.zip_longest(*data)), columns=labels)`